# How to select any property on an expanded list?

Tags: odata, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api

I have an SPFx customization that uses the SharePoint REST API to query a list and expand and select properties of one of its child lists. The request looks something like this:

`https://mine.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Parent')/items?$expand=Child&$select=Child/Property`

I'm able to get the child's `ID` and `Title` properties but when I try to select another of type bool (`IsEnabled`) it causes the query to become invalid.

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The query to field 'Child/IsEnabled' is not valid."
        }
    }
}
```

How can I craft a query to the parent list that can select the child's properties that ***aren't*** used to make the reference? I'm sure I can do it by iterating the parent's list items and making separate queries against the child list by `ID` but that's messy and inefficient; is there another way?

Comment: What type is Property? Single line of text or Choide or...?

Comment: @Matej, the one that doesn't work is a Yes/No choice. The ones that do (ID and Title) are integer and Single line of text.

Comment: Based on my knowledge Choice columns (+ lookup columns) can't be retrieved with this approach.